# How can i set the interface for the TicTacToe game project?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, layout-manager

I am trying to make the interface for the Tic tac toe. I am using the JLabels method for my 9 fields. There is no error in the program but there is something that i don't know how to do it. Please read below for my problem & please give me suggestion

```
 import javax.swing.*;
 import java.awt.*;
 import java.awt.geom.*;

 public class ticTac extends JFrame
   {
    static JLabel label0 = new JLabel();
    static JLabel label1 = new JLabel();
    static JLabel label2 = new JLabel();
    static JLabel label3 = new JLabel();
    static JLabel label4 = new JLabel();
    static JLabel label5 = new JLabel();
    static JLabel label6 = new JLabel();
    static JLabel label7 = new JLabel();
    static JLabel label8 = new JLabel();
    static JLabel[] choiceLabel = new JLabel[9];

    static ImageIcon burger = new ImageIcon("Cross.jpg");

 public static void main(String []args)
    {
        new ticTac().show();   
    }

 public ticTac()
    {
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(450,450);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);     

        getContentPane().setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints myGrid = new GridBagConstraints();

        GridBagConstraints gridConstraints;
        choiceLabel[0] = label0;
        choiceLabel[1] = label1;
        choiceLabel[2] = label2;
        choiceLabel[3] = label3;
        choiceLabel[4] = label4;
        choiceLabel[5] = label5;
        choiceLabel[6] = label6;
        choiceLabel[7] = label7;
        choiceLabel[8] = label8;
```

**This method draws the Labels from 1 to 9 in a horizontal row, so i don't want that, i want my program will draw three box in one row, and three boxes in second row and three boxes. please help me.**

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
            {
              gridConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
              choiceLabel[i].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(burger.getIconWidth(), burger.getIconHeight()));
              choiceLabel[i].setOpaque(true);
              choiceLabel[i].setBackground(Color.RED);
              gridConstraints.gridx = i;
              gridConstraints.gridy = 0;
              gridConstraints.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
              getContentPane().add(choiceLabel[i], gridConstraints);



        pack();
        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        setBounds((int) (0.5 * (screenSize.width - getWidth())), (int) (0.5 * (screenSize.height - getHeight())), getWidth(), getHeight());
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a [`GridLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html)

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import static tictactoe.TicTacToe.choiceLabel;

public class LayoutTicTacToe {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new LayoutTicTacToe();
    }

    public LayoutTicTacToe() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3, 10, 10));

                choiceLabel[0] = new JLabel("_");
                choiceLabel[1] = new JLabel("_");
                choiceLabel[2] = new JLabel("_");
                choiceLabel[3] = new JLabel("_");
                choiceLabel[4] = new JLabel("_");
                choiceLabel[5] = new JLabel("_");
                choiceLabel[6] = new JLabel("_");
                choiceLabel[7] = new JLabel("_");
                choiceLabel[8] = new JLabel("_");

                for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                    choiceLabel[i].setText("_");
                    choiceLabel[i].setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
                    choiceLabel[i].setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
                    choiceLabel[i].setOpaque(true);
                    choiceLabel[i].setBackground(Color.RED);
                    frame.add(choiceLabel[i]);
                }
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Or, if you're really stuck on `GridBagLayout`...

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import static tictactoe.TicTacToe.choiceLabel;

public class LayoutTicTacToe {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new LayoutTicTacToe();
    }

    public LayoutTicTacToe() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

                choiceLabel[0] = new JLabel("_");
                choiceLabel[1] = new JLabel("_");
                choiceLabel[2] = new JLabel("_");
                choiceLabel[3] = new JLabel("_");
                choiceLabel[4] = new JLabel("_");
                choiceLabel[5] = new JLabel("_");
                choiceLabel[6] = new JLabel("_");
                choiceLabel[7] = new JLabel("_");
                choiceLabel[8] = new JLabel("_");

                GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
                gbc.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
                int col = 0;
                int row = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                    gbc.gridx = col;
                    gbc.gridy = row;
                    choiceLabel[i].setText("_");
                    choiceLabel[i].setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
                    choiceLabel[i].setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
                    choiceLabel[i].setOpaque(true);
                    choiceLabel[i].setBackground(Color.RED);
                    frame.add(choiceLabel[i], gbc);
                    col++;
                    if (col > 2) {
                        col = 0;
                        row++;
                    }
                }
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Update with feedback**

Just some friendly feedback...

- There's really no point extending `JFrame`, you're not adding anything significant to its functionality.  Better to use `JPanel` and then add that to an instance of `JFrame`.  If nothing else, you now have the option to add it to any other container you like.
- For the most part, there's no need to use `JFrame#getContentPane` (unless you're using Java 1.4 or lower), as `setLayout` and `add` (amongst a whole bunch of others) are mapped to use `getContentPane` directly.
- If you want to center the frame in the middle of the screen, use `setLocationRelativeTo(null)`.  It's simpler to use.  Try and avoid the use of `setBounds` if you can.
- You should be ensuring that your UI is launched with the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.  Take a look at [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) for further details